# GitHub actions IOS xcode QA/Staging and issue with certificates and provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, github, github-actions

I am using GitHub actions for IOS using xcode 11.3. I am able to build, export archive and push to app center for dev environment. However, I am getting error with the staging/QA environment.

If i provide the same certificates and provisioning files that i used for dev environment in staging/QA, i am getting the error during exporting archive (build is successful):-

```
#Export Archives
##[error]Process completed with exit code 70.
Run xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath abc.xcarchive -exportPath abc.ipa -exportOptionsPlist ./abc/ExportOptions.plist          
2020-04-16 15:57:11.154 xcodebuild[7404:37990] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path '/var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/abcStaging_2020-04-16_15-57-11.153.xcdistributionlogs'.
error: exportArchive: No profiles for 'com.abc.Staging' were found
** EXPORT FAILED **

Error Domain=IDEProfileLocatorErrorDomain Code=1 "No profiles for 'com.abc.Staging' were found" UserInfo={IDEDistributionIssueSeverity=3, NSLocalizedDescription=No profiles for 'com.abc.Staging' were found, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Xcode couldn't find any iOS Ad Hoc provisioning profiles matching 'com.abc.Staging'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild.}
```

if i create new certificate(apple distribution) and provision file(Adhoc distribution) in apple developer account. Exported the files and converted the the files then uploaded .p12.gpg and mobileprovision.gpg in GitHub actions, i am getting error while build is happening:-

```
#Build archives
##[error]Process completed with exit code 65.
Run xcodebuild archive -workspace abc.xcworkspace -scheme abcStaging -archivePath abc.xcarchive
User defaults from command line:
    IDEArchivePathOverride = /Users/runner/runners/2.169.0/work/abcappIOS-v1.0/abcappIOS-v1.0/abc.xcarchive

note: Using new build system
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
error: No profiles for 'com.abc.Staging' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.abc.Staging'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild. (in target 'abc' from project 'abc')

** ARCHIVE FAILED **

##[error]Process completed with exit code 65.
```

I have provided -allowProvisioningUpdates as a parameter in export archive but the error continues

Below is the code from github actions

```
name: Deploy iOS to App Center

on:
  push:
    branches: [ staging ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ staging ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: macOS-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1

      - name: Install gpg
        run: brew install gnupg

      - name: Switch XCode Version
        run: sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode_11.3.app

      - name: Setup provisioning profile
        run: |
          chmod +x ./.github/secrets/secrets.sh
          ./.github/secrets/secrets.sh
        env:
          IOS_PROFILE_KEY: ${{ secrets.ios_profile_key }}

      - name: Install Cocoapods
        run: gem install cocoapods

      - name: Install pod dependencies
        run: |
          pod install
        shell: bash

      - name: Build archive
        run: |
          xcodebuild archive -workspace abc.xcworkspace -scheme abcStaging -archivePath abc.xcarchive

      - name: Export Archive
        run: |
          xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath abc.xcarchive -exportPath abc.ipa -exportOptionsPlist ./abc/ExportOptions.plist -allowProvisioningUpdates
```

Below is the shell script

```
#!/bin/sh
gpg --quiet --batch --yes --decrypt --passphrase="xxxx" --output ./.github/secrets/xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx.mobileprovision ./.github/secrets/xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx.mobileprovision.gpg

gpg --quiet --batch --yes --decrypt --passphrase="xxxx" --output ./.github/secrets/abc_Certificates.p12 ./.github/secrets/abc_Certificates.p12.gpg

mkdir -p ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles

cp ./.github/secrets/xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx.mobileprovision ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx.mobileprovision

security create-keychain -p "" build.keychain
security import ./.github/secrets/abc_Certificates.p12 -t agg -k ~/Library/Keychains/build.keychain -P "xxxx" -A

security list-keychains -s ~/Library/Keychains/build.keychain
security default-keychain -s ~/Library/Keychains/build.keychain
security unlock-keychain -p "" ~/Library/Keychains/build.keychain
security set-keychain-settings -lut 1500 ~/Library/Keychains/build.keychain

security set-key-partition-list -S apple-tool:,apple:,codesign: -s -k "" ~/Library/Keychains/build.keychain
```

How do create certificates, provisioning profiles for staging (non-development or non-production environments)?
Kindly advise, how do i resolve the issue with staging/qa as mentioned above?

Thanks

Comment: did you found any solution for this? I am facing the same

Comment: Stuck at the same problem as well. Please share solutions if you found any, thank you.

Comment: I was able to fix this issue, and posted my answer below. Hope anyone in the future finds it useful :)

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error and was able to figure out solution. There are many things that could be going wrong, so I'll add few points that may help you rectify the issue:

1. **Developer vs. Distribution Profiles:** You need different Developer and Distribution profiles for archive + export + deploy. xcodebuild will automatically pick the right one, but you have to create 2 different Profiles + 2 different Certificates for this purpose. This process must be done for each environment (QA, Staging, Prod etc.).

To summarize, for each environment, there will be 2 profiles and 2 certificates (certificates can be reused but not Profiles as they would depend on how many different bundles you have).

```
error: No profiles for 'com.abc.Staging' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.abc.Staging'
```

The error above suggests that you never created a Profile for com.abc.Staging, or at least didn't download + add it to the right location.

You can create them in Apple Developer Console -> Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles -> Profiles

Make sure you have Identifiers for the staging (or other) environment set up as well: com.app.staging etc.

2. **Add development Provision Profiles in XCode** and make sure the certificates are valid while building with XCode directly. Then try your scripts locally, and then push them to Github Actions.
3. Sometimes the **Profiles in Apple Developer can be invalidated** (maybe you revoked in XCode or removed the certificate etc.). This happened with me few times, so make sure to check everything is valid.
4. **Saving Provisioning Profiles by their UUID** after decryption.
   I'm not sure how important this is, but I went ahead and used it anyways.

The code is here:

```
for PROVISION in `ls ./*.mobileprovision`
do
  UUID=`/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Print :UUID' /dev/stdin <<< $(security cms -D -i ./$PROVISION)`
  cp "./$PROVISION" "$HOME/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/$UUID.mobileprovision"
done
```

The reasoning + sample code is from this article: https://medium.com/@karaiskc/archive-and-export-ios-app-with-github-actions-b44f676e4bf9

The CICD process turned out to be quite exhausting for me, but the major challenge was understanding the relationship of Certificates, Provision Profiles and  KeyChain Access, and how they work.

Answer (score 0):

I try this for using my provision profile saved in secret when base64

```dart
- name: using profile
    run : |
      echo -n "$PROVISION_PROFILE_PROD" | base64 --decode > /tmp/build_pp.mobileprovision
      mkdir -p ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles
      cp /tmp/build_pp.mobileprovision ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles
```

Where /tmp/build_pp.mobileprovision decoded file 64 and `$PROVISION_PROFILE_PROD = ${{ secrets.NAME_BASE64_VAR }}`